# Bootstrap not right-align my DIVs - pull-right not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align the two text field, shown in photo, to the right side of the screen.

I have tried all the solutions to similar questions, here on StackO.

I have tried using offset , and pull-right.  Neither worked.

### Screenshot

[image: Bootstrap Image]

#### Source Code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Search Filter -->
<div class="row filter-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-12  .col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="form-group form-focus">
      <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      <label class="focus-label">Module Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-12  .col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="form-group form-focus select-focus">
      <select class="select ">
        <option> -- Select -- </option>
        <option> Pending </option>
        <option> Approved </option>
        <option> Returned </option>
      </select>
      <label class="focus-label">Status</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-12  .col-md-offset-3">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Search </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Search Filter -->
```

as you see, the offset class I added didn't work. Can anyone help me get this stuff over to the right?

Ps. There were initially FOUR input fields, I removed the ones I didn't need. I only need these two...

Comment: Did you try `float:right`?

Comment: Yeah just make that container 100% width and float right

Comment: You have static width at all of your 'cols' so you don't have to `float` them anywhere. Just add something like `col-md-offset-3` to the first one. You have it written with dot at the start - just delete the dot.

Comment: You've done the right thing, you've just got a syntax error - remove the `.` from `.col-md-offset-3` and it works. Also, beware that if you add that class to each col it will offset each col by three.... I think what you want it to just offset the first col and let the rest follow naturally. So remove the `.` from the first col, and delete that class reference on every other col

Comment: Well, I tried all of your suggestions.  Still not working.  Here is the actual page, so you can see it in context :  http://johntesting.azurewebsites.net/modules.html

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? I applied bs3 to my previous comment example. I think they changed the syntax slightly in BS4 - try this instead of your `col-md-offset-3`..... `offset-lg-3`.
Apply it to the first column, delete the class references on the other columns, also delete the `float-right` classes, they are now redundant. Works for me when I edit your site in the devtools.

Answer (score 0):

On your .row or .filter-row class for that specific row add

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

to the class

Then remove the offset and float classes from your columns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap4, but have applied Bootstrap3 class syntax.

Migration from BS3 to BS4 meant that offset class syntax have changed from:

`col-md-offset-3`

to

`offset-md-3`

If you change the syntax on your first column, delete the class reference on subsequent columns (and also delete the `float-right` class reference which is redundant) then it works - I just edited your live example in the devtools and it works for me.